# Windows creates wireless network when hotspot is disabled

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking

I had this issue on my old laptop, and it seems to have reappeared on my new one. Running windows version 1709.

I've used the mobile hotspot feature occasionally (and it works as expected).
SSID: Hotspot

Password: thisIsAHotspot

However, when I turn off mobile hotspot, there's often still a network being broadcast from my laptop something along the lines of "DIRECT-product_name". I can't log in to it using thisIsAHotspot.

It exists as "Local Area Connection* 13" in the network connections view and is called "Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter". If I disable it, the network goes away, but then I have to go into device manager to re-enable it every time I want to use my hotspot.

How do I get it to quit broadcasting a network address when I'm not using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok that wi-fi direct virtual adapter is always turned on when your wireless display is projecting to PC.

You can disable wi-fi direct ssid broadcasts by disabling projection to PC.

- Press <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> simultaneously.
- Go to Connect wireless display → Projecting to this PC → set to "Always Off"
- Alternatively navigate to Settings → System → Projecting to this PC → set to "Always Off"

Comment: ohhhh, sure enough. That's pretty annoying... Wish I could have projection enabled without broadcasting my existence to users.